# Why does this attempt at preloading images with jQuery not work?

Tags: jquery, image-preloader

Current I have this code:

```
var imgCount = 36;
var container = $('#3D-spin');

var loaded = 0;
function onLoad()
{
    alert(loaded);
    loaded++;
    if(loaded >= imgCount)
    {
        alert('yay');
    }
}

for(var i = imgCount-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    container.prepend(
        $('<img>')
            .one('load', onLoad)
            .attr('alt', 'View from '+(i*360/imgCount)+'\u00B0')
            .attr('src', '/images/3d-spin/robot ('+i+').jpg')
    );
}
```

However, it's behaving VERY strangely. Normally, I get *no* alert boxes. However, if I open developer tools, and pause script execution, I get a single alert that says `0`. There's nothign like a good old heisenbug!

A live example can be found [here](http://technobotts.info/soccer#3D-spin). The script itself is called `style.js`, and it is clear that images have loaded.

Am I doing something stupidly, or is jQuery playing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the images have been cached by the browser, there's a chance that the onload event will not fire. What you can do is manually fire the load event for images that have their `complete` property set:

```
container.prepend(
    $('<img>')
        .one('load', onLoad)
        .attr('alt', 'View from '+(i*360/imgCount)+'\u00B0')
        .attr('src', '/images/3d-spin/robot ('+i+').jpg')
        .each(function() { if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load"); }
    );
```

Comment: +1 you are my hero. I embarrass myself by not having known about `.complete`. Great answer @karim79!